# How am I supposed to kill the final boss on the Deus Ex difficulty?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I'm not upset—I won't actually pick the game up again—but I was expecting to earn the pacifist achievement when I just completed to game but somehow didn't earn the achievement.  I can't think of any point in the game where I killed someone.

Either, I didn't get it because I didn't spot that a takedown I did was actually a lethal one,

> some of the "crazies" at the end ran into a mine when chasing me and that counted as a death,

a robot exploded and killed someone, or I did something wrong with the last boss.

> I ran to the center, hit all the pods switches then laser beamed her for about 5 seconds.

I think it took me about 20 seconds and I did it on my first attempt.  This boss was by far the easiest boss to kill for me.  Was I not meant to kill the boss this way for the pacifist achievement?  How was I supposed to kill the final boss?

Here's a video showing how I managed to defeat the boss.  Did I get a glitched final boss or is this how it is supposed to be done?

Comment: I'm not actually exagerrating on the 20 seconds point either. Looking at the "how tos" on YouTube, I dont understand how some of them are 4 minutes long... On Deus Ex difficulty it was effortless? (No one was in any of my pods either) If that was because of some gameplay choices I made?

Comment: I don't know what gameplay choices led me there, but all of my pods were filled with people I had to kill. By the way, robots exploding do not count as kills "by your hand" so you needn't worry about that.

Comment: Just repeated from my last save point, then recorded on Fraps, it took ten seconds exactly from the end of the movie to kill the boss. I just lazered her immediately and she died. A little disapointing to say the least. The best boss was the third one based on this.

Comment: Man. Wish I had thought to use the laser rifle!

Comment: Regarding the pacifist achievement, did you shoot anybody in the head with a non-lethal weapon? Sometimes the game bugs and determines them dead. See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29630/is-this-guy-dead

Comment: Yeah, I probably did. Not the end of the world. I'm not going to be playing the game again. Just wanted to comment on that.

Comment: The probably probably wasn't a boss battle. It's awfully easy to accidentally kill someone without realizing it. I knocked out a guard, who then fell into electrified water. It was just chance that I decided to search him despite his being invisible (underwater), at which point I saw he was dead. The rest of the game I obsessively checked every single body to confirm they were just asleep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They way you did it is legit.

But the other way you might want to try is:

1. Destroy the turrets or sneak up to the centre pillar.
2. Hit the switches to open the pods and hit the people in side with a non-lethal weapon or you can disable it with a level 5 hack or with a code I think given to you by Hugh Darrow.
3. This then causes a system overload of some sorts, at this point robots and crazies will come out and start looking for you.
4. You can take them out or do what I did and just hid until the system overload discharged.
5. The discharge will destroy the glass surrounding the boss, which you are then free to open lead upon or any other weapon of your choice :)

Comment: You can, instead of using the switches to open the pods, hack the terminals that are up on the raised areas to open the pods from a distance (and then tranq or shoot the people inside from a distance too).

Comment: I pushed the button and fired a grenade in there, did the trick! ;)

Comment: There is also a hackable security panel on the central pillar. With the code you get from Darrow, you can shut off life-support (and the turrets) extremely quickly. (Does not count against pacifist achievement.)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a laser rifle, you're perfectly capable of doing it your way (it won't cost you the pacifist achievement).

If you don't have the laser rifle, you have to disable all of the security before the glass lowers allowing you to shoot her.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, (and I did earn Pacifist, even though I did a lethal injection on the test subject in Dr. Cavanaugh's lab, and "purged" all three in the last fight) Boss fights completely don't count, since you kinda hafta kill them to move on.  I tried all non-lethal ways and none of them would go down any other way.  You must have inadvertently killed someone else along the way.  Even a "PEPS" can kill if it slams someone hard enough against a wall or tosses them over the edge of a building.  You did just stun "Diamond Chan" and plant the drugs in his apartment, right?

Answer (score -1):

typhoon on the terminals and then eliminate the turrets and blow out the guys and take out Zhao

Answer (score -3):

I just played the final boss fight. Once without killing crazies (no pacifist) and once with taser and non-lethal takedowns. It turns out killing those crazies means you don't get pacifist...