# I shot someone with a stun gun and now he's dead. Could I still be considered a pacifist?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I was going for a pacifist playthrough, and so I used the tranquilizer rifle and stun gun almost exclusively.

During the Cloak & Daggers side-mission, I was aiming to incapacitate Double-T, with the first obstacle being the henchman sitting on the couch outside his apartment door. I took out my stun-gun and made short work of him, but as I was dragging him away from where he collapsed I noticed that he appeared to be dead:

[image: He's just resting]

This is the first time I've had someone die after shooting him with the stun gun. Just to try it out, I reloaded and shot him with the tranquilizer rifle, only to have him die again (maybe he has a severe allergy to being unconscious).

So, is this just some sort of weird glitch, or does this actually count as a kill, thus disqualifying me for the pacifist achievement?

Comment: A similar thing happened to me: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29630/is-this-guy-dead

Comment: @yx. Ah well, it's practically the same question (finding duplicates on gaming is hard). It's funny how we also had the same response to the situation :)

Comment: This guy can be taken down without causing a death. I figured out that approaching him first, resulting in him telling you to back away, and THEN tranqing him does the trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this qualifies as a kill, sadly.  You can also get kills from the tranquilizer sniper rifle, and if you kill someone after you've knocked them out.  People have said it happens more often when you headshot with it, but frequently backing up your saves and checking everyone is the best way to go.

Comment: The strange thing is I got the "Merciful Soul" bonus for a non-lethal kill. I guess I'll use this as an excuse for stop being so cautions. Time to break out the missile launcher.

Comment: I read a lot of guides trying to get this achievement, and I managed to do it, but there were times I had to reload, even though I thought I did a clean takedown... it was frustrating.

Comment: Was it fall damage or electrical damage to his prosthetics that killed him?

Comment: Personally, I think it was glitch damage.  The Deus Ex universe is very susceptible to this type of damage.  During this mission in particular, one of the guards spawned in the ceiling of the building and glitched around before finally falling to his death from a crazy height off a garage nowhere near where he started out.

Comment: @CyberSkull I'd have to agree with agent86 on this. It can't be electrical damage, since a tranq dart also killed him when I tried that and it shouldn't have been fall damage as he was sitting on a couch when I downed him. I do suspect some sort of physics glitch, though, subjecting him to some tremendous force that caused his death.